# Center placeholder text in iPhone

Tags: iphone, css, html

Im using the HTML5 placeholder attribute for a text input. I can center the text that the user enters, but not the placeholder text for iPhones.

Ive tried the following:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, 
input:-moz-placeholder,
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder,
input::-webkit-input-placeholder, textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,
input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder,
{ 
text-align:center; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that bundling webkit and moz properties like that doesn't play nicely with webkit.  Try declaring webkit separately...

```
input:-moz-placeholder, :-moz-placeholder, 
input:-moz-placeholder, textarea:-moz-placeholder
{ 
text-align:center; 
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder, ::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder
{ 
text-align:center; 
}
```

Comment: yeah it's strange, seems to be just a safari issue

Comment: Ive marked this as correct as I can use these selectors to change the text colour on iphone, so i think centring the text must be impossible. Not the cleanest solution but ive used a background image of text to get around this. Hopefully text redering variations cross device wont be that noticeable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply any CSS to your placeholders, there's an excellent answer here:

[Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

For things like color, this seems to work just fine on iOS. Also, according to that, this is all you'd need to center your placeholders on iPhone:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    text-align:center;
}
```

I've tested this on iPhone (iOS 5.1.1), iPad  (iOS 5.0.1) and Safari (Win, 5.1.7). 
None of them seem to recognize that rule.